# Save form details in a file in JSON format JSP-Servlet

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets

I have created a registration form in jsp and then by using servlet I have retrieved those values.

In servlet, I have written code to create file and trying to save data in json format in that file.

But I am not able to save data :-(

Can I use request dispatcher to forward those values to next page?
totally in confusion...

```
        File f=new File("C:\\Users\\marslab4\\workspace\\Registration\\WebContent\\sample2.json");
        f.createNewFile();
        //out.println("json");
        /*FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(f, true);
        filewriter.write("first name:" + fname);
        filewriter.write("last name:" + lname);
        filewriter.write("user name:" + uname);
        filewriter.write("email:" + email);
        filewriter.write("password:" + pswd);
        filewriter.write("confirm password:" + repswd);
        filewriter.write("phonenumber:" + phonenumber);
        filewriter.write("security question:" + SecurityQuestion);
        filewriter.write("answer" + tarea);
        filewriter.flush();
        filewriter.close(); */

    //saving in JSON form

    JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jarray=new JSONArray();
    JSONObject details;
   try
    {
       for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
       {
               details = new JSONObject();
               details.put("firstname:",fname);
               details.put("lastname:",lname);
               details.put("username:",uname);
               details.put("email:",email);
               details.put("password:",pswd);
               details.put("confirm password:",repswd);
               details.put("phonenumber:",phonenumber);
               details.put("security question:",SecurityQuestion);
               details.put("answer:",tarea);
               jarray.put(details);
       }
               json.put("details",jarray);
    }
    catch(JSONException e)
    {
        out.print("unable to save in JSON File");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
   response.setContentType("application/json");
   response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
```

my servlet code, getting form values to Servlet and then saving to a file

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
String fname=request.getParameter("fname");
String lname=request.getParameter("lname");
String uname=request.getParameter("uname");
String email=request.getParameter("email");
String pswd=request.getParameter("pswd");
String repswd=request.getParameter("repswd");
String phonenumber=request.getParameter("phonenumber");
String SecurityQuestion=request.getParameter("SecurityQuestion");
String tarea=request.getParameter("tarea");
```

Comment: Do you need to save request in a file? or Do you need to send some information back to the client? Which problem do you want to solve first?

Comment: hi @alayor Firstly i need to save into file.Later on i need to parse that JSON object to display to client

Comment: Why haven't you been able to save into a file? Are you able to get data from client into the servlet?

Comment: In txt file i can able to save.But, i need it to be saved in JSON format.."first name:ganeshlast name:pasupuletiuser name:ganeshpemail:ganesh@gmail.compassword:jhansi123confirm password:jhansi123phonenumber:9999999999security question:foanswerbchboifhbxhifhg "

Comment: I guess you can use the same code to save in txt file - but calling writer method this way `filewriter.write(json.toString());`

Comment: i tried.. SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Registration] in context with path [/Registration] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause

Comment: Well, we need to see what that root cause is. You need to provide more information about the errors you're having so that you can receive quick help. Maybe you could add that error message in the description.

Answer (score 1):

You could try below code:

```
File f = new File("C:\\Users\\marslab4\\workspace\\Registration\\WebContent\\sample2.json");        
FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(f, true);
filewriter.write(json.toString()); // Pass json object.
filewriter.flush();
filewriter.close();
```

Instead of passing each request parameter separately, you should pass your created json object as shown above.

Hope this helps.